# TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory is missing in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot application version 1.5.x, which uses `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`, I'm trying to migrate it to Spring Boot 2, but the app does not compile, although a have a dependency to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat`. The compiler issues the error below:

```
error: package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463908/unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-servletwebserv)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The class has been removed and replaced by `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory`
For more info check: [Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#embedded-containers-package-structure), which says:

> In order to support reactive use cases, the embedded containers
>   package structure has been refactored quite extensively.
>   EmbeddedServletContainer has been renamed to WebServer and the
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded package has been relocated
>   to org.springframework.boot.web.server. Correspondingly,
>   EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer has been renamed to
>   WebServerFactoryCustomizer.
>
> For example, if you were customizing the embedded Tomcat container
>   using the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory callback interface,
>   you should now use TomcatServletWebServerFactory and if you were using
>   an EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer bean, you should now use a
>   WebServerFactoryCustomizer bean.

I had the problem that I needed to sent bigger request, then the default size allowed:

```
@Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
                int maxSize = 50000000;
                super.customizeConnector(connector);
                connector.setMaxPostSize(maxSize);
                connector.setMaxSavePostSize(maxSize);
                if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {

                    ((AbstractHttp11Protocol <?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(maxSize);
                    logger.info("Set MaxSwallowSize "+ maxSize);
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 85):

In Spring boot [2.0.0.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#embedded-containers-package-structure) you can replace with following code::

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector redirectConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    return connector;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I did differently is this line:

`Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);`

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am getting `IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set` if I do that - any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: I did as you mentioned but when I am hitting my application on http, it is still giving me error : Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.      Ideally this error comes when there is no connector. Could you please let me know if I need to do anything else. I am hitting the URL : http://localhost:8443/

Comment: Hi @displayname, for the `No ServletContext set`, i did a simple demo to understand and shared my finding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971937/ugrade-spring-boot-2-0-0-rc2-exception-no-servletcontext-set/61140479#61140479). If you are interested :)

Comment: Hi @Anurag, you need to hit http://localhost:8080, or the http port you have set in connector.setPort(your_http_port). If you are hitting, https://localhost:8443, make sure you have at least the self-signed certificate in place, and the required properties in application.properties to tell Tomcat where the certificate is, what the password is and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Great Thx! 
I came from this article: 
https://blog.swdev.ed.ac.uk/2015/06/24/adding-embedded-tomcat-ajp-support-to-a-spring-boot-application/

using spring boot 2.1.3:

```
@Configuration
@Data
public class TomcatConfiguration {

@Value("${tomcat.ajp.port}")
int ajpPort;

@Value("${tomcat.ajp.remoteauthentication}")
String remoteAuthentication;

@Value("${tomcat.ajp.enabled}")
boolean tomcatAjpEnabled;

@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {

    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    if (tomcatAjpEnabled)
    {
        Connector ajpConnector = new Connector("AJP/1.3");
        ajpConnector.setPort(ajpPort);
        ajpConnector.setSecure(false);
        ajpConnector.setAllowTrace(false);
        ajpConnector.setScheme("https");
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(ajpConnector);
    }

    return tomcat;
  }

}
```

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.3.2 I'm getting: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The AJP Connector is configured with secretRequired="true" but the secret attribute is either null or "". This combination is not valid.`