# ugrade spring boot 2.0.0.RC2 exception No ServletContext set

Tags: spring-boot

After debugging, the problem is that mvc configuration class EnableWebMvcConfiguration load too early, servlet not loaded yet.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$125/98506158.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at com.manway.BccApplication.main(BccApplication.java:16) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:485) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5de64506.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$40(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5de64506$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$edc706a5.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5de64506.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 43):

"After debugging, the problem is that mvc configuration class EnableWebMvcConfiguration load too early, servlet not loaded yet."

I spent a few hours on this.
I managed to find a reason why this was happening.
My config was split into several files and I was creating a MVC related bean in the Security Config (which was created earlier) forcing to use the MVC config before its time.

The solution was to move the @Bean instance from the security config to the MVC config.
I hope it helps other people!

Comment: In my case it was `MessageSource` bean, which has been defined in `WebMvcConfigurer` configuration class and at the same time was injected in creation of some other bean in the same class using `messageSource()` method calling. When I removed method-calling injection and injected `messageSource` using `@Autowired` into the same class, then this strange error become far more obvious: "Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?". So I extracted `MessageSource` bean into another configuration class, it works

Comment: Helped me too! Thanks

Comment: Seriously, saved me the hours you spent... Thanks for the hard work!

Answer (score 12):

**I have the same "No ServletContext set" issue, and i wanted to understand by doing a simple demo.**
**Notes:**
(1) The example i am using is *slightly* different from the OP but *the concept and issue is the same*.
(2) I have removed some logs that are not relevant.

**DEMO: SIMPLE Spring Boot Application:**
(1) a main class `BeanLoadingDemoApplication` annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`,
(2) a `class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, which overrides `configure` method
(3) and a couple of test beans, 1 in a stand-alone `@Configuration` class, and the other one in the main `@SpringBootApplication` class

*P.S1 `WebApplicationContext` object is the **Spring Container**, that is based on your *business* bean definitions, stored in the ServletContext of the web application.

P.S2 So after it's initialized, you will see your beans being initialized(testBean and testBean2, in my example).*

The logs after starting the application is as follows. Just focus on **where** this part is in the logs:

> ```
> INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 700 ms
> INFO  c.example.demo.WebSecurityConfiguration - WebSecurityConfiguration() - Constructor
> ```

```
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - Starting BeanLoadingDemoApplication 
INFO  o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 700 ms
INFO  c.example.demo.WebSecurityConfiguration - WebSecurityConfiguration() - Constructor
INFO  com.example.demo.TestBeanConfiguration - #############################
INFO  com.example.demo.TestBeanConfiguration - @Configuration - @Bean - testBean()
INFO  com.example.demo.TestBeanConfiguration - #############################
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - #############################
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - @SringBootApp - @Bean - testBean2
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - #############################
INFO  c.example.demo.WebSecurityConfiguration - =======================================
INFO  c.example.demo.WebSecurityConfiguration - @Configuration - WebSecurityConfiguration - @Override configure
INFO  c.example.demo.WebSecurityConfiguration - =======================================
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - Started BeanLoadingDemoApplication in 1.371 seconds (JVM running for 2.326)
```

So far ok? Simple, right? Now i add a

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() { 
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
...
}
```

in class `WebSecurityConfiguration` to configure a 2nd connector for Tomcat. Just focus **where** this part has "moved":

> WebSecurityConfiguration() - Constructor

Can you see that the constructor is called right after starting the application and has been constructed before the root `WebApplicationContext` is initialized? By now, the issue is clear.

```
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - Starting BeanLoadingDemoApplication
INFO  c.example.demo.WebSecurityConfiguration - WebSecurityConfiguration() - Constructor
INFO  o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) 8080 (http)
INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 785 ms
INFO  com.example.demo.TestBeanConfiguration - #############################
INFO  com.example.demo.TestBeanConfiguration - @Configuration - @Bean - testBean()
INFO  com.example.demo.TestBeanConfiguration - #############################
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - #############################
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - @SringBootApp - @Bean - testBean2
INFO  c.e.demo.BeanLoadingDemoApplication - #############################
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

The reason is since `Spring Boot` is initializing the embedded `Tomcat` before creating its own `WebApplicationContext`, it therefore needs to *configure* the connector i am *adding* to `Tomcat` via the `@Bean` **before initializing Tomcat and before Root WebApplicationContext is initialized!!** But because my `@Bean` is in `WebSecurityConfiguration class`, that class is getting constructed much earlier than it should have been and it will not have a ServletContext as a result!!

The solution is to move this

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    ...
}
```

in a `@Configuration` stand-alone class, so that the constructor of `WebSecurityConfiguration` is not called earlier than it should have been, and by doing so, it will get the `ServletContext` it needs.

I hope this "visual" example helps.

Cheers

Comment: Detail Example ! Thank you