# spring boot automatic redirect http to https

Tags: http, spring-boot, redirect, https

Good day, I have the application with microservices and gateway (zuul) built on SpringBoot 2. It is all uses SSL.
I need the automatic redirect from: http:\\localhost (currently shows nothing) to https:\\localhost (shows some text), so the user doesn't need to bother.

Once again: http:\\localhost has to show the same text as https:\\localhost (I need a redirect)

I've tried, does nothing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

Tried another approach, but SpringBoot failed to recognize TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector
            = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    return connector;
}
```

this one doesn't work either (doesn't seems to change anything)

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // other security configuration missing

        http.portMapper()
                .http(80) // http port defined in yml config file
                .mapsTo(443); // https port defined in yml config file

        // we only need https on /auth
        http.requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").requiresSecure()
                .anyRequest().requiresInsecure();
    }
}
```

and this one ain't working too, the error is  *Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set*

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory httpsRedirectConfig() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory () {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
}
```

and even this one with the  *java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set* error

```
  @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Got it.
Thanks to ***EstebanGarciaAlonso*** and his answer [ugrade spring boot 2.0.0.RC2 exception No ServletContext set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971937/ugrade-spring-boot-2-0-0-rc2-exception-no-servletcontext-set)

> "After debugging, the problem is that mvc configuration class
>   EnableWebMvcConfiguration load too early, servlet not loaded yet."
>
> I spent a few hours on this. I managed to find a reason why this was
>   happening. My config was split into several files and I was creating a
>   MVC related bean in the Security Config (which was created earlier)
>   forcing to use the MVC config before its time.
>
> The solution was to move the @Bean instance from the security config
>   to the MVC config. I hope it helps other people!

I moved following code to Application.java just before main method and all worked like miracle

```
   @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
```

Comment: What are the imports or dependencies necessary for this solution? When I paste in the code (I'm a Java noob), there's red squiggles everywhere, and when I hover over `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` the Quick Fix my IDE suggests is "create class" instead of doing an import.

Comment: package org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server;
    public interface ServletWebServerFactory


  package org.apache.catalina.connector;
    public class Connector


  package org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web;
    public SecurityConstraint()

Comment: May be I am late, but the above code works fine in a separate configfile, created within the same package as the main application. For eg: if my main appln(main.java) is in package *com.test.main*, I created a config package *com.test.main.config* and copied the above code to the config.java file in the config package