# How to run a fully FIPS compliant Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, fips

I have to fulfill the following criteria:

- Tomcat runs in FIPS mode
- JDK uses FIPS ssl Provider

which is expected to make the application "run in FIPS mode". Is this assumption correct?

I think [Tomcat is configured using an APR Lifecycle Listener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/listeners.html#APR_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener), with APR requiring [certain native components to be installed](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html#Installation). After these components are available, one can enable APR with [this](https://gist.github.com/andreldm/7f89a3279438467a0bd41e6c1249d014) (considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49094956/3890673)). Correct?

> Note to self: [Not everybody thinks of APR to be a good idea](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7376#issuecomment-320691933).

Now FIPS SSL Provider [seems to be related to SunJSSE](http://websecuritypatterns.com/blogs/2009/08/12/enabling-java-with-fips-140-compliant-ssltls-solution/), and it seems [there are JAR files providing functionality for this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SECMG/fips.htm#SECMG768). Is this correct? Are these JARs sufficient for Tomcat as well, despite not being native?

These are a lot of questions, I know. But basically it's **how to run a *fully* FIPS compliant Spring Boot application**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Part 1: "Tomcat runs in FIPS mode", on Ubuntu

Preface #1: Some general (yet incomplete) instructions can be found [here](https://medium.com/@crueda/tomcat-native-openssl-in-spring-boot-2-0-a341ad07471d).

Preface #2: The following requires OpenSSL with FIPS 140-2 Certified Modules. On Ubuntu these are only available for "Ubuntu Advantage Advanced customers" on Ubuntu 16.04! See [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/fips-140-2-certified-modules-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts) and [here](https://docs.ubuntu.com/security-certs/en/#fips).

- `$ sudo apt install libapr1 libapr1-dev`
  (from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html#Installation), might be `sudo apt install libapr1-dev libssl-dev` though, see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/))
- Download *tomcat-native-1.2.23-src* from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/), extract, go to `tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native/`
- `$ ./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/path/to/java-home/ --with-ssl=yes`
- `$ make`
- Add `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native/.libs` to jvm args
- add the following to your project

```java
import org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.Ssl;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AprConfig {

  @Bean
  public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
      @Override
      public Ssl getSsl() {
        // avoid "IllegalStateException: To use SSL, the connector's protocol handler must be an AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol subclass":
        return null;
      }
    };

    // enable APR:
    factory.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol");

    AprLifecycleListener aprLifecycleListener = new AprLifecycleListener();

    // will throw "FIPS was not available to tcnative at build time. You will need to re-build tcnative against an OpenSSL with FIPS." with default OpenSSL:
    aprLifecycleListener.setFIPSMode("on");

    factory.addContextLifecycleListeners(aprLifecycleListener);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

### Part 2: "JDK uses FIPS ssl Provider"

Java uses JCE ["to use stronger versions of standard algorithms"](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-all-download-5170447.html). That required to install according policy files for JDKs up to 8u161, 7u171, and 6u16; "on those versions and later the policy files are included, but not enabled by default", while "JDK 9 and later ship with, and use by default, the unlimited policy files".

JCE is an interface which is implemented by some "provider" (like JDBC is an interface which must be implemented). While there's even an implementation by Oracle, there are not many FIPS compliant providers (see [this list](https://csrc.nist.rip/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm)). And I found only one to claim Java 11 compatibility, which is the ["Bouncy Castle Crypto API"](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) in version 1.0.2 - currently "available for early access", see [Java FIPS Roadmap](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_java_roadmap.html). So Java version is to be considered here as well ([see](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/37250#issuecomment-483577860)).

### Conclusion

Running a fully FIPS compliant Spring Boot application requires

- some configuration (see above)
- an OS with FIPS compliant libraries *supporting your Java version*