# Spring boot Test fails saying, Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

Test Class:-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { WebsocketSourceConfiguration.class,
        WebSocketSourceIntegrationTests.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
                "websocket.path=/some_websocket_path", "websocket.allowedOrigins=*",
                "spring.cloud.stream.default-binder=kafka" })
public class WebSocketSourceIntegrationTests {

    private String port = "8080";

    @Test
    public void testWebSocketStreamSource() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        ClientWebSocketContainer clientWebSocketContainer = new ClientWebSocketContainer(webSocketClient,
                "ws://localhost:" + port + "/some_websocket_path");
        clientWebSocketContainer.start();
        WebSocketSession session = clientWebSocketContainer.getSession(null);
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("foo"));
        System.out.println("Done****************************************************");
    }

}
```

I have seen same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463908/unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-servletwebserv) but nothing helped me. May I know what I'm missing ?

I have `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as compile time dependency in the dependency Hierarchy.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This message says: 
*You need to configure at least 1 ServletWebServerFactory bean in the ApplicationContext*, so if you already have spring-boot-starter-tomcat y**ou need to either autoconfigure that bean or to do it manually**.

So, in the test there are only 2 configuration classes to load the applicationContext, these are = { WebsocketSourceConfiguration.class, WebSocketSourceIntegrationTests.class }, then at least in one of these classes there should be a @Bean method returning an instance of the desired ServletWebServerFactory.

*** SOLUTION ***

Make sure to load all the beans within your configuration class

```
WebsocketSourceConfiguration {
  @Bean 
  ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory(){
  return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
  }
}
```

OR also enable the AutoConfiguration to do a classpath scanning and auto-configuration of those beans.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
WebsocketSourceConfiguration
```

Can be done also at the Integration Test class.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
WebSocketSourceIntegrationTests
```

For more information check the **SpringBootTest** annotation documentation 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html

Comment: Also:
`import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration;
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, ... })`

Comment: what is WebSocketSourceIntegrationTests exactly here?

Comment: @bharal WebSocketSourceIntegrationTests is the name of the class posted in the description/question.

Comment: For me, this happened when I had `@Configuration` instead of `@TestConfiguration` in my test config class (listed under "classes" in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation)

Comment: Simply adding the `@TestConfiguration` annotated config class (and nothing else) solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on a test class helped me!

Answer (score 1):

in **2.0.5.RELEASE** i faced a similar issue when I had the following.

```
package radon;
..
@SpringBootApplication
public class Initializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }
}

package radon.app.config;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "radon.app" })
public class Config {
    ..
}
```

Changing the package of Initializer from `radon` to `radon.app` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is because `spring` is not able to load the properties file at `runtime`, i was using `spring` profiles and wasn't providing the (program or vm) argument at `runtime( java -jar application.jar)` , adding vm argument of profile resolved the issue for me.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev application.jar
```

or using program argument

```
java -jar application.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.location=c:\config
```

Comment: Use correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability.

Answer (score -2):

#### For web applications, extends `*SpringBootServletInitializer*` in main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourAppliationName extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourAppliationName.class, args);
    }
}
```

If not working check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232382/6831257

Comment: Same issue even after trying this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50232382/6831257
check this answer