# Unable to start web server due to missing ServletWebServerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot-jpa

I have looked on Stack Overflow a few days ago. My problem seems to be very common, but I cannot manage to fix it.

I've tried these ways [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231736/applicationcontextexception-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext/50232382) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264118/spring-boot-test-fails-saying-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontex).

This is my application.propreties :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

When I tried to run it, it is giving me following errors :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; 
nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean
```

These is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApplication {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>toto</groupId>
    <artifactId>toto</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Run the spring boot in idea or eclipse debug mode, you will get to know the actual issue.

Comment: Can you show your main class?

Comment: can you give us your pom.xml or build.gradle ?

Comment: thanks i ve added on the post the pom and the main class,

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the following property from your application.properties file

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

it means that you don't need a web server in your application.

Comment: Okay i did but a new error appeared : 
     Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project toto: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro programmer, but what I would do if I were you :

1. Make sure you have a proper project structer
2. Check the basic configuration guides from[Spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)!

I have my personal project where I training with Spring Framework usage, maybe you will get something usefull from it,[project link](https://github.com/ThomasBolivar/YtoDo)!

Good luck and have fun :)

Comment: thanks thomas, but I tried to follow the  baeldung's tuto (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate). it doesn t work.

Comment: Try to compare my config files and pom.xml and yoursm perhaps it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your main class should be like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApplication {
    
    @Autowired
    BookRepository repository;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```