# How to resolve the error of starting Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am a beginner, I hope to help me analyze the reasons, thank you.

I followed the tutorial to create a Spring Boot project, and when I ran it, there was an error

The various environment variables are also configured

When I try to access http://localhost:8080, it looks like this

[image]

#### Environment

- macOS Sierra10.12.6
- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 (Ultimate Edition)
- Maven 3.6.0
- Spring Boot 2.1.3

#### Error log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2019-03-08 14:26:39.289  INFO 41209 --- [           main] top.changxuan.demo.DemoApplication       : Starting DemoApplication on bogon with PID 41209 (/Users/changxuan/IdeaProjects/demos/target/classes started by changxuan in /Users/changxuan/IdeaProjects/demos)
2019-03-08 14:26:39.294  INFO 41209 --- [           main] top.changxuan.demo.DemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-03-08 14:26:40.875  WARN 41209 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2019-03-08 14:26:40.891  INFO 41209 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-08 14:26:40.915 ERROR 41209 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at top.changxuan.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:206) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

#### pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>top.changxuan</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463908/unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-servletwebserv

Comment: add this dependency to your pom.. <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: kumar, thanks your suggest, but isn't work. the new error log ：java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)  and so on

Comment: run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` likely this is a corrupted jar.

Comment: The answer is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264118/spring-boot-test-fails-saying-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontex).

Answer (score 1):

It works fine as is. Possibly issue with the configuration / workspace problems in IntelliJ.

Used the below **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>stackoverflow-55058264</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the main class **DemoApp.java**

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Run the `DemoApp` and access the endpoint: `http://localhost:8080`, which should respond back with a **White-Label Error page**.

Its tested and verified.

I would suggest you to switch to a different workspace in your IDE and try.

Comment: thanks, 
It is still wrong, I will try other methods. ERROE LOG:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-08 21:14:49.631 ERROR 43802 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation seems correct it could be due to pom. You have to up do maven updation and  if not working then try to change version of spring boot.
Then run again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem!

You need to go to the maven repository to remove the tomcat-embed-core.jar package and then update the Maven repository.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDZ5R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRuL7.png)